# KML created by Google Earth Engine can't be read on Google MyMaps

Tags: google-maps, google-earth-engine

I have a FeatureCollection in Google Earth Engine, and I'm exporting it to a kml (and storing on Google Drive) using the code below:

```
// Export the FeatureCollection to a KML file.
Export.table.toDrive({
  collection: fcPR,
  description:'citiesOfParanaToDrive',
  fileFormat: 'KML'
});
```

The permissions are set to Public (anyone can read and access the data).

And when I try to import it in Google MyMaps, I get the message: "The file contains invalid or not supported data, or is bigger than supported". Opening in Google Earth (installed application on computer) works.

Reading the documentation, the max number of lines is 2000, but my file contains only 400.

Is there some step that I am missing?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

I am assuming that you've already hit the [troubleshooting page from Google](https://support.google.com/mymaps/answer/3024937?hl=en), where you got the 2000 line limit. But you may want to verify that your file size is under the file size limit. See this SO question: [Issues With KML Layers Limit](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/10804070/issues-with-kml-layers-limit) and verify that the other limits have not been exceeded:

> Maximum fetched file size (raw KML, raw GeoRSS, or compressed KMZ):
>   3MB
>
> Maximum uncompressed KML file size: 10MB
>
> Maximum number of Network
>   Links: 10
>
> Maximum number of total document-wide features: 1,000

Comment: You are right. The KML uncompressed file is 11MB, so I guess that this is the problem. Regards.